# query to search dates which are stored as string in the database

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

I have a table where I store an activity completion date as `varchar`. The format of the date stored is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS`.
I have search window where I have two fields `Completion date from` and `completion date to`.The date format selected here is `MM/DD/YYYY`.

How do I write a query such that I am able to fetch the activity completion between two given dates from the table which has the dates stores as varchar.This table was created a long time back and no thought was given to saving dates as datetime.

Comment: I would put the effort into fixing the schema. Any query is likely to be horrible both in terms of the SQL and the performance, and *everyone* will benefit from a better schema.

Comment: I am sure it definitely would have helped.fixing the schema is one of the last options here.

Comment: Not just "would have helped" but "will help in the future".

Comment: If I have the date stored as the following format MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS Z e.g. 26/03/2014 04:48:27 BRT (Brasília time) ,10/09/2014 05:51:32 BRST(Brasília Summer time)how would I convert this to datetime?

Comment: You would ask a new question with more details...

Answer (score 4):

You can use SQL `CONVERT` to change your columns to `DATE` format but that will cause performance issues.

```
SELECT *
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate) >= CONVERT(DATE, '01/01/2014')
        AND CONVERT(DATETIME, MyDate) <= CONVERT(DATE, '01/31/2014')
```

`CONVERT` documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

if you are unable to change how data is stored, than for better performance , you can create view with calculated column that converts `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`. After that can create index on calculated column. [Index on Computed Column documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

**You could use this code :**

```
 select * from table_name
 where  CAST(col1 as date )  
between CAST(Completion date from as date ) 
        and CAST(Completion date to as date);
```

**Function syntax CAST:**

```
CAST ( expression AS data_type )
```

Comment: `STR_TO_DATE` is not [tag:SQL-SERVER] function.

Comment: ohhh ! my bad ! i thought  it was mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use the SUBSTRING function to get the date parts in a comparable order (i.e. yyyymmdd):

```
select *
from mytable 
where 
  CONCAT( SUBSTRING(thedate, 7, 4) , SUBSTRING(thedate, 4, 2) , SUBSTRING(thedate, 1, 2) )
between
  CONCAT( SUBSTRING(@FROMDATE, 7, 4) , SUBSTRING(@FROMDATE, 4, 2) , SUBSTRING(@FROMDATE, 1, 2) )
and
  CONCAT( SUBSTRING(@TODATE, 7, 4) , SUBSTRING(@TODATE, 4, 2) , SUBSTRING(@TODATE, 1, 2) )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below if the date format is {yyyy-MM-dd}, or you can adjust the charindex's index value depending on format

```
SELECT * 
FROM table
WHERE 
    CHARINDEX('-', col_value, 0) = 5 
    AND CHARINDEX('-', col_value, 6) = 8
    AND LEN(col_value) = 10
```

The above piece will look for first occurrence of char '-' at position 5 and the second char '-' at position 8 while the entire date value's length is equal to 10 chars

This is *not full proof*, but will narrow down the search. If you want to add **time** then just expand the criteria in the where to accommodate the format i.e. {yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000}

This is a safe way to query the data, without any unexpected 'invalid cast / convert' errors.